# UIActionSheet iOS 8 error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uiactionsheet, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to show `UIActionSheet` on iPad from button on `UITableViewCell`. It works fine on iOS 7, but not working properly on iOS 8. `UIActionSheet` containts some visual artifacts and I'm getting this warning in console:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79793de0 H:[UIView:0x797a7630(304)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a16ae00 UIView:0x7a16ab60.width == _UIAlertControllerView:0x797a9230.width>",
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a66f2a0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7a16ab60(298)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797a49e0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x797a9230.width >= UIView:0x797a7630.width>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x79793de0 H:[UIView:0x797a7630(304)]>

    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

My code:

```
- (void)onFavoriteBtn:(id)sender {
    CGPoint btnPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPosition];
    if (indexPath) {
        UIButton *favoriteBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
        CGRect favoriteBtnRect = favoriteBtn.frame;

        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Remove from Favorites" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [sheet showFromRect:favoriteBtnRect inView:favoriteBtn.superview animated:true];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated, so you can use `UIAlertViewController` available in iOS 8.0 or later.

```
- (IBAction)onFavoriteBtn:(id)sender {
    CGPoint btnPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPosition];
    if (indexPath) {

        [self showActionSheet:sender];
    }
}

- (void)showActionSheet:(UIView *)sender
{
    NSString *alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"ActionTitle", @"Archive or Delete Data");
    NSString *alertMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"ActionMessage", @"Deleted data cannot be undone");

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                                             message:alertMessage
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", @"Delete action")
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Delete action");
                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *archiveAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Archive", @"Archive action")
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Archive action");
                                    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:deleteAction];
    [alertController addAction:archiveAction];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
    if (popover)
    {
        popover.sourceView = sender;
        popover.sourceRect = sender.bounds;
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    }

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You suggest to decide whether to use UIActionSheet or UIAlertController at runtime based on iOS version?

Comment: @user1561346 Yes exactly.

Comment: `UIAlertController` have the same appearance bug and the same warning in console. Didn't expect that, really. :/ And of course I've added `alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect` and `alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView`.

Comment: I have tried the same code at my end and everything working fine as expected. Check your storyboard may be there has some constraints issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your favorite button superview is too small to embed action sheet. Try to use window to display action sheet, just don't forget convert coordinates of favorites button:

```
- (void)onFavoriteBtn:(id)sender {
    CGPoint btnPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPosition];
    if (indexPath) {
        UIButton *favoriteBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
        CGRect frame = [self.window convertRect:favoriteBtn.bounds fromView:favoriteBtn];
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Remove from Favorites" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [sheet showFromRect:frame inView:self.window animated:true];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that view must be large enough to fit it. It's used just to find a position. But I've tried to convert frame to self.view and to self.navigationController.view.